# Weak dimension of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, global-dimension

I was wondering if there is a characterization of rings of weak dimension one.
For example, we know that a ring of weak dimension zero is a von Neumann regular ring.

Is there a similar result for rings of weak dimension one?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rings with weak dinmension $1$ are the rings with all (three-generated) ideals syzygetic. More precisely, we have the following result:

*Theorem:* Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(1) The weak dimension of $R$ is $\le 1$.

(2) Every ideal of $R$ is of linear type.

(3) Every ideal of $R$ is syzygetic.

(4) Every three-generated ideal of $R$ is syzygetic.

Reference: Rings of weak dimension $1$ and syzygetic ideals, PROCEEDINGS OF THE
AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY, Volume 124, Number 10, October 1996.

Comment: Wow, an interesting type of ring I have not heard of before (syzygetic) and it's no wonder: I don't really understand coherent rings and the like :)